# How to move coordinate position of Flash Download Progress Bar?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, progress-bar, preloader

I am extending the Flash DownloadProgressBar component for use as a preloader with Flex.  Is it possible to override the x and y coordinate position of the progress bar? (the default is to center the bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, have to override functions barFrameRect, barRect, borderRect and labelRect.  Was confusing because couldn't figure out how to override the progress bar positioning for SparkDownloadProgressBar.